# jQuery works after 5 or 6 refresh

Tags: php, jquery, html

i want to make an edit page, when the user go to a question (i have a question website) he will have a choice to edit that question , and when the user click to edit question , i want to get all the information about that question from database and put it in an edit page , i did that and it works good with all information , but i have a problems and it is :

on my edit page i have many drop down lists and each drop down get its options from database using ajax with jquery

my problem is in the last 4 drop down lists

the first drop down list is     `what the question about` 
,it has 3 options `place , cell ,general`
 the second drop down list is what `the city that question about` , it has 14 values 
the third drop down list is what the `cell the question about` and its options comes depends on the second drop down list options , i mean if the user set a city on the second drop down list , the cell drop down list will have many options , but if he changed the city , the user will have new options in the cell drop down list
,the forth drop down is `what the place that the question about` 
so when i open the edit page i have to fill those drop down list with its value , each one according to the previous drop down list,
,i did that , but my problems is the page works good after 4 or 5 refresh , not from the beginning ,i mean i have to refresh the page 4 or 5 times to get the good results , `because on the first refresh the drop down list still empty , but i alert the results each refresh and i got the expected results`

**SOME OF HTML**

```
<?php
  $questionInfo = $this->questionInfo->fetch();
  $questionPlaceCountry = $this->questionPlaceCountry->fetch();
  $questionCell = $this->questionCell;
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
  var typeName= '<?php echo $questionInfo["typeName"]; ?>';
  var place = '<?php echo $questionPlaceCountry["placeName"]; ?>';
  var country = '<?php echo $questionPlaceCountry["countryName"]; ?>';
  var cell = '<?php echo $questionCell; ?>';
</script>

<li>
  <label>About</label>
  <select name="about"id="aqAboutQuestion"></select>
  <span class="errorMessage"></span>
  <p id="aqCoutryAboutQuestion">
    <label>Select City</label>
    <select name="city"class="CountrySelector1"></select>
  </p>
  <p id="aqCellAboutQuestion">
    <label>Select Cell</label>
    <select name="cell"></select>
    <span class="errorMessage"></span>
  </p>
  <p id="aqPlaceAboutQuestion">
    <label>Select Place</label>
    <select name="place"></select>
    <span class="errorMessage"></span>
  </p>
</li>
```

**SOME OF JQUERY CODE**

```
$.getJSON(
  "http://localhost/Mar7ba/Type/getAllTypes/TRUE",
  function(data){

    var options = '';
    options+="<option>Select Type</option>";

    for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
      options += "<option value='"+data[i]+"'>"+data[i]+"</option>";
    }

    if($("#addPlace #apTypeSelect").length){
      $("#addPlace #apTypeSelect").html(options);
    }

    if($('.TypeSelector').length){

      $('.TypeSelector').html(options);
      if("#editOneQuestion"){

        $('.TypeSelector').val(typeName);
        if(place!=null){

          $("#aqCoutryAboutQuestion").css("display","block");
          $("#aqCellAboutQuestion").css("display","block");
          $("#aqPlaceAboutQuestion").css("display","block");
          $("#aqAboutQuestion").val("Place");

          $("#aqCoutryAboutQuestion select").val(country);

          $.getJSON(
            "http://localhost/Mar7ba/Cell/getCellsInCity/"+country+"/TRUE",
            function(data1) {

              var optoins1 = '';
                  optoins1+="<option>Select Cell</option>";

              for(var i=0;i<data1.length;i++){
                optoins1+="<option value='"+data1[i]+"'>"+data1[i]+"</option>";
              }

              $("#aqCellAboutQuestion select").html(optoins1);
              $("#aqCellAboutQuestion select").val(cell);
          });

          $.getJSON(
            "http://localhost/Mar7ba/Place/givePlacesInCell/"+cell+"/TRUE",
            function(data2){

              var options2 ='';
              options2+="<option>Select Place</option>";
              for(var i = 0 ; i < data.length;i++){
                options2+="<option value='"+data2[i]+"'>"+data2[i]+"</option>";
              }
              $("#aqPlaceAboutQuestion select").html(options2);
              $("#aqPlaceAboutQuestion select").val(place);
          });
        }
      }
    }
});
```

would you help me and tell me what am i doing wrong ?

Comment: where are you loading your jQuery from?

Comment: from database , mysql database

Comment: You have to explain your problem better... it is hard to guess from " i have to refresh the page 4 or 5 times to get the _good_ results"

Comment: you're loading jQuery from MySQL? :$

Comment: @the_archer and for each refresh i alert the results and it is the expected results , but i don't know why it doesn't print on the drop down lists

Comment: You're not loading jQuery from mySQL, but probably from a link to jquery.js, google API or something similar. Have you placed all your javascript inside a document.ready function? Your variables seems a bit off, some are "optoins" and some are "options", and on that note, you are using rather long selectors, you're sure you typed them all correct. Caching some of them would probably be a good idea.

Comment: @adeneo no from mysql ,just mysql , and i know there is options and optoins , the page is working after 5 or 5 refreshes that means there is no syntax or or grammer error , and i don't think caching is a good idea because i have to cash all the database , because i don't know which options will the user select

Comment: @adeneo i think it is the time for getting data from database , so it takes a many refresh to work , like if the brower cash the results and after 5 refresh the browswer will be got all the results ,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is that because probably you are using

```
$(document).ready()
```

but you have to use:

```
$(windows).load()
```

Comment: yes totti  ,it works , really thank you  , and your nickname like my ones :) :) , really thank you for helping